# REST api add body for authorization in google app scripts

Tags: rest, google-apps-script

I am using google app scripts, trying to log in, get token and then get my data with this API:
https://www.sensorpush.com/gateway-cloud-api
Couldn't understand the syntax required to login and get the token, this is my code:

```
function restAPI() {
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var username = scriptProperties.getProperty("username");
  var password = scriptProperties.getProperty("password");
  var options = {'muteHttpExceptions': true};
  var url = 'https://api.sensorpush.com/api/v1/oauth/authorize'
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log(response);
}
```

Obviously I get an error:

{"message": "Missing Authentication Token", "type": "MISSING_AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN", "statusCode": "400" }

Comment: `payload` key in `options` is body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- From the endpoint of your showing script and [your provided official document](https://www.sensorpush.com/gateway-cloud-api), you want to convert the following curl command to Google Apps Script.

  ```
    curl -X POST "https://api.sensorpush.com/api/v1/oauth/authorize" \
    -H "accept: application/json" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d @- <<BODY
    { 
       "email": "<email>", 
       "password": "<password>"
    } 
    BODY
  ```

In this case, how about the following modification?

From the sample curl command, it seems that the request body is `{"email": "<email>","password": "<password>"}`, and this is required to be sent as `application/json`.

#### Modified script:

```js
function restAPI() {
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var username = scriptProperties.getProperty("username");
  var password = scriptProperties.getProperty("password");
  var options = {
    method: "post",
    contentType: "application/json",
    payload: JSON.stringify({ email: username, password: password }),
    headers: { accept: "application/json" }
  };
  var url = 'https://api.sensorpush.com/api/v1/oauth/authorize';
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log(response);
}
```

- In this modification, it supposes that the value of `username` is your email address. And also, it supposes that the values of `username` and `password` are valid values. Please be careful about this.
- I think that the request for this modified script is the same as the above curl command. But, if an error occurs, please confirm your values of `username` and `password` again.

#### Reference:

- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)